# Angular 2 dual data binding on input element not working

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, onchange

Refer to the code below, whenever the input value changes, the textchange function will be called.  However, the text property of the InputMaskComponent never changes.  Not sure what's wrong with my code.

**InputMaskComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'inputs:mask',
    templateUrl:'InputMaskComponent.html'
})
export class InputMaskComponent{
    pattern: string;
    text: string;
    dom: Element;
    constructor(el:ElementRef, @Attribute('pattern') pattern:string){
        this.dom = el.nativeElement;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
    textchange(event:any){
        console.log(this.text, event);
    }

}
```

**InputMaskComponent.html**

```
<div>
    <input  type="text" 
            [placeholder]="pattern" 
            (input)="textchange($event)" 
            [(value)]="text" />
    <span #child class="hidden"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
</div>
```

**RootComponent.html**

```
<input:mask pattern="(###) ### - ###">(012) 345 - 678</input:mask>
```

Comment: what is `(input)`, `[(value)]`? why are you not using `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: I agree. Why are you not using `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: @micronyks and @yurzui are right, you should use `NgModel` directive for two-way binding, but your case requires to break it into two parts - `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` because you want to invoke a function when input changes. Replace `[(value)]` with `[ngModel]` and `(input)` with `(ngModelChange)` and everything will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
[(value)]="text"
```

means that you bind

- `text` property of the components class to the `value` property of the `<input>` element
- the `valueChange` event to the event handler `text = $event`

but the `<input>` element doesn't emit a `valueChange` event.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#two-way